# Why does Regex raw string prefix "r" not work as expected?

Tags: python, regex, backslash

I learned that "`r"\n"` is a two-character string containing `'\'` and `'n'`, while `"\n"` is a one-character string containing a newline. Regular expressions will often be written in Python code using this raw string notation." And the `r"\n"` is equivalent to `"\\n"` to denotes two-character string `'\'` and `'n'`.

I test it by printing and it works

```
>>>print(r"\n") or print("\\n")
'\n'
```

However, when I tested in regex

```
>>>import re
>>>re.findall("\d+", '12 cats, 10 dogs, 30 rabits, \d is here')
['12', '10', '30']
>>>re.findall(r"\d+", '12 cats, 10 dogs, 30 rabits, \d is here')
['12', '10', '30']  # Still the same as before, seems 'r' doesn't work at all
>>>re.findall("\\d+", '12 cats, 10 dogs, 30 rabits, \d is here')
['12', '10', '30']  # Doesn't work yet
```

When I tried this, it works though

```
>>>re.findall(r"\\d+", '12 cats, 10 dogs, 30 rabits, \d is here')
['\\d']
>>>re.findall("\\\d+", '12 cats, 10 dogs, 30 rabits, \d is here')
['\\d']
>>>re.findall("\\\\d+", '12 cats, 10 dogs, 30 rabits, \d is here')
['\\d']  # Even four backslashes
```

Why? Does this mean I have to add one more backslash when using regex to make sure it is a raw string?

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: `"\d+"` isn't a string where the backslash has any non-literal meaning, so it works whether or not it's specified with raw syntax. However, the raw syntax is clearer to a human reader -- they don't have to think about whether `"\d"` is parsed differently, as `"\t"` or `"\n"` or such are.

Comment: Raw strings disable Python's backslash processing. They do not disable the regex engine's backslash processing; that would completely defeat the purpose of raw strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that `"\d+"` works is that `"\d"` is not a proper escape sequence in Python strings and Python simply treats it as a backslash followed by a "d" instead of producing a syntax error.

So `"\d"`, `"\\d"` and `r"\d"` are all equivalent and represent a string containing one backslash and one d. The regex engine than sees this backslash + "d" and interprets it as "match any digit".

`"\\\d"`, `"\\\\d"` and `r"\\d"`, on the other hand, all contain two backslashes followed by a "d". This tells the regex engine to match a backslash followed by a "d".